# Rails "validates_uniqueness_of" Case Sensitivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

Here is the model (I am using SQLLite3):

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_uniqueness_of :name

end
```

For example, after I add "Yale", I cannot add "Yale" but *can* add "yale." How can I make the validation case insensitive?

EDIT: Found it - [Active Record Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

`validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false` does the trick, but you should keep in mind that `validates_uniqueness_of` does *not* guarantee uniqueness if you have multiple servers/server processes (e.g. running Phusion Passenger, multiple Mongrels, etc) or a multi-threaded server.  That's because you might get this sequence of events (the order is important):

1. Process A gets a request to create a new user with the name 'foo'
2. Process B does the same thing
3. Process A validates the uniqueness of 'foo' by asking the DB if that name exists yet and the DB says the name doesn't exist yet.
4. Process B does the same thing and gets the same response
5. Process A submits the `insert` statement for the new record and succeeds
6. If you have a database constraint requiring uniqueness for that field, Process B will submit the `insert` statement for the new record and *fail* with a ugly server exception that comes back from the SQL adapter.  If you do not have a database constraint, the insert will succeed and you now have two rows with 'foo' as the name.

See also "Concurrency and integrity" in the [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002110) Rails documentation.

From [Ruby on Rails 3rd Edition](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition):

> ...despite its name, validates_uniqueness_of doesn’t really guarantee that column values will be unique. All it can do is verify that no column has the same value as that in the record being validated at the time the validation is performed. It’s possible for two records to be created at the same time, each with the same value for a column that should be unique, and for both records to pass validation. The most reliable way to enforce uniqueness is with a database-level constraint."

See also [this programmer's experience](http://blog.insoshi.com/2008/06/26/working-around-the-validates_uniqueness_of-bug-in-ruby-on-rails/) with `validates_uniqueness_of`.

One way this commonly happens is accidental double-submissions from a web page when creating a new account.  This is a hard one to solve because what the user will get back is the second (ugly) error and it will make them think their registration failed, when in reality it succeeded.  The best way I've found to prevent this is just to use javascript to try to prevent double-submission.

Comment: As a note -- here's a patch I've submitted to Rails to try to fix this problem by utlizing db-level constraints:  https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/3486-alternative-to-validates_uniqueness_of-using-db-constraints

Comment: also, there's the perennial "user double clicked the submit button" problem, but that's more of a fix using :disable_with

Answer (score 88):

In rails 3 you can do this in your model:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => true
```

or without case_sensitivity

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
```

**The same solution applies to Rails 6**

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want.

Comment: I have been doing Rails for over 10 years.  I can't believe I'm just learning about this option.  There's always something new to learn in Rails...regardless of one's skill level.

Answer (score 27):

There is an option where you can specify case insensitivity

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question but the answer is more interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422771

Basically, using `:case_sensitive => false` performs a very inefficient database query.

Comment: That may have been true at one time, but now (rails 6 at least, if not earlier) it performs a very efficient EXISTS query. That query during validation wouldn't be able to take advantage of a regular index on `name`, but in order to guarantee concurrency, there ought to be a unique index on `lower(name)` anyway, and the query would indeed be able use that.