# validate uniqueness in rails4 and case sensitivity fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

`validates :name, uniqueness: true`

The above validates `name` with case sensitive uniqueness. Any other default validators/options exists to include to  case-insensitive checking.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I found this code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987482/2754188

You can use this line:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `text`-column, then the following should easily work:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name
```

The `default` setting for case_sensitivity is `:true` and you can even add the following to your validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false
```

This setting is however ignored by non-`text` columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on uniqueness of a record in Rails app, then please be reminded about this Rails article which says that Rails uniqueness is not fool proof. Scroll down to the bottom of this article [Rails - Concurrency and integrity issues](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) to know in detail.

In short, duplicates can still occur during concurrent operations.

I have faced these issue of duplicates in Rails app during concurrency and I had to apply a database level unique index on the table.