# Rails 4 - uniqueness validation doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, email, unique

I am using this block of code for validating email address. The format of entered email address validates well, but the problem is with the "uniqueness" part - I currently can enter more identic email addresses to the database - how is that possible?

Has something changed in Rails 4 about validations?

```
class BetaAccess < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :email,:with => Devise::email_regexp, uniqueness: true
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: I had a same problem, I edited uniqueness part as in separate line. Try it also `validates_uniqueness_of :email`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422211/rails-3-validating-email-uniqueness-and-case-sensitive-fails

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class BetaAccess < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email,format: {with: Devise::email_regexp}, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: It should be noted this takes advantage of the [`validates`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview) method introduced in Rails 4 (I think?). Don't use `validates_x_y` any more ;)

Comment: valides was introduced in Rails 3

Answer (score 1):

`format` and `uniqueness` are different validators, if you want to use in one line, you should use `validates` method.

```
validates :email, :format => { :with => Devise::email_regexp }, :uniqueness => true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_format_of :email,:with => Devise::email_regexp, uniqueness: true
```

combines uniqueness into the validation for format. Use the `validates` syntax

```
validates :email,format: {with: Devise::email_regexp},
                 uniqueness: true
```

Also, use the new ruby syntax for hashes. Kind of neat that way