# Need to check whether email exists and then update record if it does. Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am just trying to update certain attributes of a record based on whether the email address exists or not.

Controller:

```
def update
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

        if @contact.update then
            redirect_to :root, notice: 'yes was successfully updated.'
            else
            render "new"
            end
        render "show"
    end
```

Model:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
has_attached_file :image, styles: {large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "150x150#"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
    #validates :email, uniqueness: true
    validates :email, presence: true
end }
```

Definitely know there's a lot wrong with this and would kindly like some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, there are many things to improve here, first let me explicitly answer your question:

```
validates: email, uniqueness: true
```

By adding that validation in your contact model, the update method will return `false` so the email will not be updated. You can also ignore case_sensitivity by adding `case_sensitive: false` to the validation.
You should keep in mind that this validation does not guarantee uniqueness if you have multiple servers/server processes (e.g. running Phusion Passenger, multiple Mongrels, etc) or a multi-threaded server. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/690851/5446424) for an extended explanation.

However, that will not work on the code you paste above, let me explain why:

1) The update method requires passing 1 argument, so your code will throw an `ArgumentError` there.

2) `render` appears more than one time in the same method: This will throw you the following error

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

You will need to refactor your code there.

For `redirect_to: root`, make sure to configure to root route first.

3) This line `Contact.new(contact_params)` does not return an existing record. The new method creates an object instance, so you would not be updating anything there.

A possible solution for your method could be:

```
helper_method :contact

def update
  if contact.update(contact_params)
    flash[:success] = "Contact updated"
    redirect_to :root
  else
    render :edit
  end   
end

private

def contact
  @contact ||= Contact.find(params[:id])
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I make those edits above and implemented your solution I receive an error. Couldn't find Contact with 'id'=

Comment: That's because either you don't have a record with the specified id or you're not receiving it by param. As a suggestion, I would create a base_controller to catch the errors and make this controller to inherit from that. In this case the exception you need to catch is `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`